# PHP Javascript/CSS Packaging Tool (like Haste/Juicer)

Tags: php, javascript, css

In this video:
http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=596368660334

Facebook talks about their implementation of Haste -- a CSS and Javascript packaging tool.

Juicer seems to be very similar
https://github.com/cjohansen/juicer/

Haste seems to be available onto Facebook engineers and Juicer is Ruby, I am looking for a PHP version that is available.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to watch the video, but it sounds like your looking for something like http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Comment: That looks like a decent option (and similar to a custom one I have now), but one of the aspects that I am looking for is this feature from Juicer "figure out which files depend on each other and merge them together, reducing the number of http requests per page view, thus improving performance "

Answer (score 1):

Celerity is similar to Haste and is part of phabricator, developed at Facebook only. You can more into this at here [Celerity Documentation](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Celerity_Technical_Documentation.html).